# Ignore directories with Guard

Tags: ruby, minitest, guard

I'm using guard-minitest to automatically run my tests.

I also have a skeleton gem inside the `test/fixtures` directory.

The problem is, now Guard is running the tests in the skeleton gem also.

How can I tell Guard to only run my tests for my actual project and not any projects in the `test/fixtures` directory?

I've tried the following, but it isn't working:

```
guard :minitest, :exclude => "test/fixtures/*" do
  # with Minitest::Unit
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.*/)?([^/]+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})      { 'test' }
end
```

Edit:

The [docs](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples) make it seem like I can add an ignore path, this also didn't work:

```
ignore %r{^test/fixtures/}

guard :minitest do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.*/)?([^/]+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})      { 'test' }
end
```

Edit:

As recommended below I tried removing the asterisk, also doesn't work:

```
ignore %r{^test/fixtures/}

guard :minitest do
  watch(%r{^test/test_(.*)\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.*/)?([^/]+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})      { 'test' }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a more specific directory, add a more specific watcher regular expression, and add a `test_folders:` options [docs](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest#list-of-available-options)

This is my working guard file and test dir:

```
guard :minitest, test_folders: 'test/real' do
  watch(%r{^test/real/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.*/)?([^/]+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/real/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})      { 'test/real' }
end
```

dir structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 test
test
├── fixtures
│   └── newgem
└── real
    ├── devify
    ├── test_devify.rb
    └── test_helper.rb

4 directories, 2 files
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `watch(%r{^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})` uses a regular expression that matches the tests of the gem skeleton.
So if you have these files:

```
test/my_real_tests/test_one.rb
test/my_real_tests/my_gem/test_two.rb
```

`/my_real_tests/my_gem/` is matched by the first `(.*)`.

Add a more concrete regular expression so they are not matched. Something like `watch(%r{^test/my_real_tests\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})`. Or just remove `(.*)`.

Here's the [documentation](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-DSL---Configuring-Guard#watch) about how `watch` works.

Also: Why is a gem skeleton in `test/fixtures` ? Seems odd :)

Comment: Can you add a reference to the [documentation](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest#list-of-available-options) about changing the `test_folders:` option then I can accept this!

Comment: Sure, it's in the Guard documentation, not in guard-minitest

Comment: Can you check out my edited question? I don't think editing just `watch` works, I also needed to add the `test_folders:` option which is a `minitest` plugin option

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and found that adding a decoy folder structure like the two suggested answers is a bit hacky.

A better solution IMO is to modify your regex to negate the fixtures folder:

`watch(%r{^test/(?!fixtures)(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})`